# Use Python to read console output from a swig generated function

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm using python to graph data that was generated in C++ code. In my C++ code, I generated and stored data using arrays and output the data to console.

So the output from compiling the c++ code is this:

0    1.38889    1.38889    1.38889    1.38889    100
0    2.08333    2.77778    2.77778    52.0833    100

...20 or so more iterations

Now, on the Python side of things, I can use my function and it outputs the data to the console,but I can't actually store the data in a list or something

Here is what my python code looks like:

```
import heat

heat.heat()

print heat.heat()

type(heat.heat())
```

output:

> 0  1.38889 1.38889 1.38889 1.38889 100
>
> 0  2.08333 2.77778 2.77778 52.0833 100
>
> ...
>
> 0  24.7484 46.755  67.0274 84.5801 100
>
> 0  24.7664 47.2768 67.0564 84.9026 100
>
> 48
>
> type 'int'

I'm new to swig, so my naming convention is terrible, but in my C++ code, I only needed one function to import, so that's why it's like that. My `heat.heat()` function is using Jacobi iteration to solve a heat conduction problem where values have been hardcoded in the C++ file for now. Basically I just want to be able to graph the data, but my `heat.heat()` function only outputs to the screen.

Comment: _Now, on the python side of things, I can use my function and it outputs the data to the console,but I can't actually store the data in a list or something_ unclear to me what you mean in here?

Comment: show your code, and your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the [subprocess.check_output() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output). This function allows you to execute arbitrary commands/programs and capture their output as a string in Python. Example:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output("command to execute", shell=True)
```

The variable "output" now contains the output from your command which you can parse with any of the usual [string methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). You may or may not need the `shell=True` argument depending on your use case. The main difference is whether or not the command will be executed in your default shell environment or simply as a subprocesses. The docs have more detail and some warnings you should read. (Don't set it to true if the "command to execute" may be coming from untrusted sources!)

You won't be able to capture the output of native python functions with this, so you have two options:

1. Since you're trying to capture output from a compiled C++ executable, you may be able to execute it as your "command to execute".
2. If your `heat()` function is doing more than simply calling the executable, you can use `subprocess.check_output()` in a wrapper script that launches your existing script, and move all your output processing into *that* script.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion, but what happened was my command outputted the data to the console, but then gave some error messages.TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Is it possible that your executable is writing to stderr instead of stdout? Try adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to your call to `check_output`.

Comment: output = subprocess.check_output(heat.heat(),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,shell=True)  is still giving me the same error int object is not iterable

Comment: Note this part of my answer: "You won't be able to capture the output of native python functions with this". Pretend your current script is called "heat.py". Write a second script that has this: `output = subprocess.check_output("python heat.py", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`. The subprocess module is used to execute external commands, not Python functions in the same script. Add your string parsing and data processing to the new script after that call.